# How to create a scrollable tablesroter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter Pager plugin but it seems to result in some problems with me. So I think create a scrollable tablesorter would be the way for me to go. But I haven't got any luck to find such solution yet. Anyone has ideas about this?

Appreciated!

Comment: you mean having a scroll for the table

Comment: yes I mean create a scroller for the tablesorter plugin, when the records are going beyond the page the overflow will show a scroll bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has nothink to do with plugin for the sorter you can incorporate another plugin for scroller that would only take care of scrolling so you can you two plugins one for sorting one for scrolling 
 here are couple

http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/

http://www.flexigrid.info/

http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links for me. I actually find one js plugin specifically for tablesorter (http://tconnell.com/samples/scroller/). The tablefixedheader is pretty good tho at my first seeing it.